# Alter text field focus order with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, textbox, focus, textfield

I was wondering, if I have text fields displayed so, could I alter the order in which the focus using javascript (preferably jQuery).

See this example [here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/Trufa/PjfCK/).

What I mean that when you tab around them, instead on going "one, two, three, four, five" force them to go: "one, two, four, three, five".

Thanks in advance!!

**EDIT:** Thanks to all, I didn´t know it was possible with HTML only. Of course if this is the case I´ll go with that.

BTW Thanks to all your answers!!! (I`ll upvote the complete ones) but will accept the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for jQuery! Check out [tabIndex](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_tabindex.asp).

Answer (score 3):

Set the [`tabindex`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html) attribute on the elements.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5S93D/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the tabIndex property to have the order of tabbing as needed:
e.g.:

```
<input type="text" tabIndex=1 value="one"/><br />
<input type="text" tabIndex=2 value="two"/>
<input type="text" tabIndex=4 value="three"/><br />
<input type="text" tabIndex=3 value="four"/>
<input type="text" tabIndex=5 value="five"/>
```

But if you want to dynamically change the tabbing at client side, you can use jQuery .attr function.

```
$(<YOUR ELEMENT SELECTOR>).attr("tabIndex", "YOUR_VALUE");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set the [`tabindex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.tabIndex) attribute, like this:

```
<input type="text" value="one" tabindex="1" /><br />
<input type="text" value="two" tabindex="2"/>
<input type="text" value="three" tabindex="4" /><br />
<input type="text" value="four" tabindex="3" />
<input type="text" value="five" tabindex="5" />
```

...no JavaScript required.  [You can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/hv39G/).

Answer (score 1):

You would set the **[tabindex](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex)** attribute with jQuery's [**attr** method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

In your case we need to use the [eq selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) because your elements have no id.

```
$("input:eq(0)").attr("tabindex","1");
$("input:eq(1)").attr("tabindex","2");
$("input:eq(2)").attr("tabindex","4");
$("input:eq(3)").attr("tabindex","3");
$("input:eq(4)").attr("tabindex","5");
```

[**Try it here!**](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nMum5/)